# Shell rename a lot of files recursively

Tags: linux, bash, shell, file, rename

I want to rename a lot of files in sub directories with a shell script/command, and I've tried different way without any success.

Here is the files I've got:

```
root/FOLDER1/media-125150-payasage151.jpg
root/FOLDER1/media-125165-payasage125.jpg
root/FOLDER2/media-1266165-payasage110.jpg
root/FOLDER2/media-1266165-portrait151.jpg
```

and I want to replace every "payasage" by "paysage"

```
root/FOLDER1/media-125150-paysage151.jpg
root/FOLDER1/media-125165-paysage125.jpg
root/FOLDER2/media-1266165-paysage110.jpg
root/FOLDER2/media-1266165-portrait151.jpg
```

I've tried RegExr with rename command or even with a mv approch...
thanks!

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1136/batch-renaming-files

Answer (score -1):

Try something along the lines of

```
for OLD in root/*/media-*-payasage*.jpg; do
  NEW=$(echo "$OLD" | sed 's/payasage/paysage/g')
  test "$OLD" != "$NEW" && mv "$OLD" "$NEW"
done
```

Comment: Unnecessary sed usage. Use `NEW="${OLD//payasage/paysage}"`. [Bash String Manipulation](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html)

Comment: Unnecessary indeed - but readability trumps efficiency in this setting: The rename itself will take orders of magnitude more resources than the `sed`

Comment: On windows:  `time for ((i = 0; i < 100; ++i)); do OLD="haha"; echo "$OLD" | sed "s/ha/hu/g" > /dev/null; done`: 3.9s whereas `time for ((i = 0; i < 100; ++i)); do OLD="haha"; echo "${OLD//ha/hu}" > /dev/null; done`: 0.006s

Comment: On Windows this might be true.The question is tagged as `linux` though

Comment: I was hoping you would copy paste this in your linux environment :) So we could compare.

Comment: Ah, I see: `real 0m0.047s / user 0m0.004s / sys 0m0.023s` vs. `real 0m0.004s / user 0m0.004s / sys 0m0.000s` on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Summary: for only a few times you won't notice a difference but if you have many renames to do, using sed is 10x slower (in this example).

Comment: That is plain wrong: The  syscall to rename the file itself  takes orders of magnitude longer, so the only thing taking longer is a tiny fraction of the total. Expect a less than 0.1% slowdown in real-world cases

Comment: I agree. I can't edit my comment anymore unfortunately.

Comment: No problem - maybe this discussion is a good reference for future searchers